# Is there a web app to keep track of my expiring domains

Tags: reminder, domain-name

Between my personal projects, one-offs for work and other sites where I'm the defacto web guy, I have a few dozen domain names that I would like to keep track of with several registrars and a few TLDs.

Is there an app that monitors in such a way ?

Ideally I'd just like one email a month with the domains that are expiring and the registrars with which they are associated.

Comment: Don't the registrar all email you when they're about to expire? I know GoDaddy does (multiple times).

Comment: Yes they usually email someone, but over a few years I've accumulated domains registered to many different addresses and some registrars (like GoDaddy) spam me about expiring domains as a chance to upsell other services and real notices get lost in the flood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UrlPad](http://urlpad.net/) does just what you want.

Comment: The awesome: it exports a calendar. The less awesome: it seems a little abandoned, it's a little awkward to add 40 domains at a time and it doesn't support .ca domains

Comment: Yeah, I've just seen this. I even created [a bug in their bugtracker](http://getsatisfaction.com/geekvoice/topics/name_is_too_long) because I got an error when trying to log in with OpenID, but they don't seem to react... A pity, because it looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider setting reminders in [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/about.html) with the option of repeating it every year. You can choose to receive [notifications](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/topic.py?topic=15300) by email and SMS.